# VPN connected but timeout when ping

Tags: networking, vpn, azure

Don't know if I can move a post from Stackoverflow to here, I think I should post my question here (copied here now):

0

I have a vpn (created in Azure) connection to validate, I can see from ipconfig on my laptop with ip of 10.1.10.1

```
PPP adapter Vnet-prod:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.10.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

The remote server (on Azure) has an ip of 10.1.0.5

On laptop when I ping the remote server, it times out.

Any thing I am missing here and how do I check/fix it?

Thank you very much.

UPDATE:

VPN configuration on Azure:
[image]

Comment: Why do you need to ping the server?

Comment: I want to do some vpn connection testing

Comment: How does ping test the VPN? You've already tested the VPN by connecting to it. How does ping accomplish anything? What's your specific use case for ping that it will tell you anything other than ICMP traffic is passing over the VPN?

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the OP with a configuration screenshot, I want to test that I can connect to a virtual machine with IP of the same section of the VPN. The local ipconfig shows I have an ip of 10.1.10.1, there is a virtual machine with ip of 10.1.0.5, I thought I should be able to connect to it via the VPN, if connected, I will know the VPN is truly working as expected.

Comment: Surely the machine you want to connect to is serving something? Web app, Database, RDP, whatever, it must have a purpose for you to connect to it, so do that, don't rely on ping. ICMP traffic is routinely blocked in a number of places in Azure  and as Joe said, its not a useful test.

Comment: Thank you Sam, indeed I just started learning Azure and the VM has nothing installed yet, but I will install maybe a database and try again. Very  interesting to know that ICMP traffic is routinely blocked in a number of places in Azure.